# Automatically inserting a header in vim

Tags: python, command-line, vim

Is there a way to auto add a header when i open a new file in vim?
My objective is to automatically add the shebang `"#! /usr/bin/python"` when i open a new file using the command `"vim test.py"`. If the file is already present, no header should be inserted.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Add this line in your configuration file:

```
autocmd BufNewFile *.py 0put =\"#!/usr/bin/python\<nl>\"|$
```

Answer (score 3):

This might be over-kill, but you could look at one of the snippet scripts for Vim, e.g. snipMate -- http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540

But, for what you want, you might just map a key to a command that reads in a file.  For example:

```
nmap <leader>r :r boiler_mashbang<cr>
```

And, then put your boilerplate in the file: boiler_mashbang.

Comment: With snipMate, you still need to explicitly type a trigger, but the idea is right; there are several "insert template" plugins on vim.org.